# How to unzip files using PHP if safe mode is on and you can't install extensions?

Tags: php, zip

Are there any PHP-scripts out there that can unzip regular zip-files? The requirements we have is that we must run with safe_mode on and we're not allowed to install any extensions to enable this functionality. Thus, any functionality must be regular php scripts.

Any thoughts?

---

EDIT: Unfortunately, neither of the posted solution works for us. We may not change the safe_mode requirement unless switching hosts, which is currently not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pclzip.lib.php is a fairly popular and well used php class that is able to extract zip file susing pure php

http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/index.en.php

Answer (score 2):

The usual answer here is [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php) or [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-open.php). However, according to the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.requirements.php):

> ### PHP 4
>
> The bundled PHP 4 version requires [» ZZIPlib](http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/), by Guido Draheim, version 0.10.6 or later
>
> ### PHP 5.2.0 or later
>
> This extension uses the functions of [» zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) by Jean-loup Gailly and Mark Adler.

So, both need external dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you ask them to disable safe mode for a single folder using a .htaccess directive such as:

```
php_value safe_mode "0"
```

and put the unzip script in there?

If so, then something like:

```
$output = shell_exec('unzip /path/to/file');
```

Would do it

Comment: This would probably be disabled in safe mode

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2495.html

It uses the gzip extension but that's installed on almost every server (I hope, check with phpinfo() )

Comment: We couldn't get this to work at all unfortunately, the zip files were just purged with this class. Possibly because of the server setup. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on linux/unix you can run

```
exec("unzip file.zip");
```

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the `safe_mode_exec_dir.`